# django-tinymce removes bootstrap HTML code

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg, django-cms, django-tinymce

I'm using/testing django-cms (2.3.5) + bootstrap based templates.
Using django-tinymce I add the code:

```
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="next">›</a>
```

But django-tinymce removes "data-slide="next""

```
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#this-carousel-id">›</a>
```

And of course nothing works.

Using WYeditor I found no way to modify the options in settings.py.
Using tinyMCE I can :

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG={
    # General options
    'mode': "textareas",                   
    'theme': "advanced", 
    'remove_linebreaks': "false",

    'convert_urls': "false",
    'relative_urls': "false",
    'theme_advanced_resizing': "true",
    'paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste': "true",
    #'preformatted': "true",

    'valid_elements': "+*[*]",

    'width': "100%",
    'height': "300px",    

    'theme_advanced_buttons1' : "formatselect,separator,bold,italic,hr,separator,link,unlink,separator,bullist,numlist,separator,undo,redo,",
    'theme_advanced_buttons2' : "|,help,code,|",
    'theme_advanced_buttons3' : ""  ,
    'theme_advanced_blockformats' : "p,h1,h2,h3,blockquote",
    'theme_advanced_toolbar_location' : "top",
    # Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    #'content_css': 'css/example.css',    
    #'content_css' : "/media/css/tiny_editor.css" 
}
```

Workflow:

- I open the HTML popup
- I copy the code
- I reopen the popup and the wanted code is there
- I save the page and I reopen the popup and the code has changed!

How can I avoid this behavior?

I also added the options to keep the spaces/tabs/comments/, to keep the absolute path, but /static/images/path/ is always converted to ../../../../../static/*.

What do I have to check/change?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/1529. Ok, hence only solution will be to create my own plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to declare `data-slide` as a valid attribute of a link/a-tag.
Have acloser look at the [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements) setting of tinymce

Comment: Thanks for replying! Why is it not working using 'valid_elements': "+*[*]",? I already checked valid_elements, but I only specified valid_elements: "a[data-slide]," and it removed other a attributes, except for data-slide. I don't want to specify all attributes. The same with extend_valid_elements

Comment: I'm almost sure it's Django-cms that removes "data-slide" attribute. If open, update the code in the tinymce popup and I reopen it the code is kept. When I save the page, Django "somehow" sanitizes the HTML.

Comment: well, this is possible too

Comment: Linked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774076/django-cms-editors-and-html-data-attribute-cleaned-up

Answer (score 1):

i belive the removing of the fields is done by html5lib that the cms uses as python package, you'll need to open html5lib folder and open sanitizer.py, in line 184 where the code is:

```
if name in self.allowed_attributes])
```

change to:

```
if name in self.allowed_attributes or re.match( r'data-.*',name)])
```

this will allow all data-(whatever) attributes

for WYMeditor the data-(whatever) attribute is already allowed

Answer (score -1):

"false" and "true" change on False and True

Comment: This doesn't really answer the original question.