# django-cms editors and HTML data attribute cleaned up

Tags: django, django-cms

Using django-cms 2.4 I need to create pages that contain bootstrap code, but the html5lib used cleans data-* attributes. No matter if you specify valid_element in TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG. (I still looking for a similar option for Wymeditor), because this is done in #plugins/text/models (clean_html function: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/1529 )

Github issue:
https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/1529

What could it be a possible workaround?
How can I extend the text plugin in the admin part?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting `'extended_valid_elements': '*[*]'` in your `TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG`?

Comment: I tried, but it's the clean method based on html5lib in Django that "cleans" the code. (https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/1529)

Comment: Hmm. I'll try to take a look at the html5lib and see what's up.

Comment: Basically all attributes are whitelisted (http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Sanitization_rules). I should extend the Django text plugin, but I don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i belive the removing of the fields is done by html5lib that the cms uses as python package, you'll need to open html5lib folder and open sanitizer.py, in line 184 where the code is:

```
if name in self.allowed_attributes])
```

change to:

```
if name in self.allowed_attributes or re.match( r'data-.*',name)])
```

this will allow all data-(whatever) attributes

for WYMeditor the data-(whatever) attribute is already allowed

Comment: Thanks! I don't like to touch external application code, but I don't see any other solution!